# How can I check if my stopword removal algorithm is working?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I'm pretty familiar with Python at this point, but new to NLP.

I've printed the result out and it *seems* to be doing what I want, but how can I verify that?

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
function_words = []

for word in tokens:
    if word.lower() not in stop_words:
        function_words.append(word)
```

'tokens' is an array I've defined earlier in my code.

Comment: Write unit tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the answer is as obvious as the following, or if I'm missing something. Since stop_words is a simple list, and printing it allows you to verify that for example, 'ourselves' is in it, you can indeed, as suggested, write a simple unit-test:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
tokens = ['ourselves', 'computer']
function_words = []
for word in tokens:
    if word.lower() not in stop_words:
        function_words.append(word)
if not function_words == ['computer']:
    print('Something went wrong!')
```

That should do the trick (you may want to consider playing around with assert (https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively), or make it more fancy in other directions, but this basic example should answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to be careful with it because the algorithm I was using before had a semantic issue that made it look like it worked, but for longer strings, it wouldn't work (it had to do with the way I was deleting elements in the array).